# Choose closest point to origin with reinforcement learning

Tags: machine-learning, keras, reinforcement-learning

I am attempting to use reinforcement learning to choose the closest point to the origin out of a given set of points repeatedly, until a complex (and irrelevant) end condition is reached. (This is a simplification of my main problem.)

A 2D array containing possible points is passed to the reinforcement learning algorithm, which makes a choice as to which point it thinks is the most ideal.

```
A [1,  10]
B [100, 0]
C [30, 30]
D [5,   7]
E [20, 50]
```

In this case, `D` would be the true best choice. (The algorithm should ideally output `3`, from the range `0` to `4`.)

However, whenever I train the algorithm, it seems to not learn what the "concept" is, but instead just that choosing, say, `C` is *usually* the best choice, so it should always choose that.

```
import numpy as np
import rl.core as krl


class FindOriginEnv(krl.Env):

    def observe(self):
        return np.array([
            [np.random.randint(100), np.random.randint(100)] for _ in range(5)
        ])

    def step(self, action):

        observation = self.observe()

        done = np.random.rand() < 0.01  # eventually

        reward = 1 if done else 0

        return observation, reward, done, {}

    # ...
```

What should I modify about my algorithm such that it will actually learn about the goal it is trying to accomplish?

- Observation shape?
- Reward function?
- Action choices?

Keras code would be appreciated, but is not required; a purely algorithmic explanation would also be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sketching out the MDP from your description, there are a few issues:

- Your observation function appears to be returning 5 points, so that means a state can be any configuration of 10 integers in [0,99]. That's 100^10 possible states! Your state space needs to be much smaller. As written, `observe` appears to be generating possible actions, not state observations.
- You suggest that you're are picking actions from [0,4], where each action is essentially an index into an array of points available to the agent. This definition of the action space doesn't give the agent enough information to discriminate what you say you'd like it to (smaller magnitude point is better), because you only act based on the point's index! If you wanted to tweak the formulation a bit to make this work, you would define an action to be selecting a 2D point with each dimension in [0,99]. This would mean you would have 100^2 total possible actions, but to maintain the multiple choice aspect, you would restrict the agent to selecting amongst a subset at a given step (5 possible actions) based on its current state.
- Finally, the reward function that gives zero reward until termination means that you're allowing a large number of possible optimal policies. Essentially, any policy that terminates, regardless of how long the episode took, is optimal! If you want to encourage policies that terminate quickly, you should penalize the agent with a small negative reward at each step.